# Agregar CSS a MPDF

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Estoy intentado agregar `CSS` a mi `MPDF`,cuando le quito las lineas del `CSS` funciona normalmente, tengo mi archivo `CSS` en en la misma ruta de mi `PHP`,me da errores con `CSS` este es mi código :

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf.css'); // la ruta a tu css

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output('reporte.pdf','I');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los errores y warning parecen ser por un problema de compatibilidad entre algunas versiones de MPDF con ciertas versiones de PHP 7 (se puede ver en un [reporte de errores del proyecto online](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/278)).

Comment: Hay una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15519335/3695983) en el sitio en inglés, el usuario Leri sugiere hacer algo como esto: `$stylesheet = "<style>" . file_get_contents('pdf.css') . "</style>";`  (aplicado a tu código, es envolver el CSS entre etiquetas `style`, y parece que le funcionó al usuario... aunque luego la respuesta aceptada no tiene nada que ver con eso y la documentación no indica que hagan falta). Prueba a ver si te funciona.